# How to replicate wwwroot over multiple IIS web servers with NLB without NAS?

Tags: windows, iis, replication, dfs, nlb

We're adding a second server with Windows NLB for a bit of redundancy (ie the power goes on one of the servers - I know its not the best solution).

How can we keep the data identical between the servers? Dont want to use a SAN or NAS as thats just something else to go wrong. Customers can upload images with the web app so changes could be made on either server, as well as us uploaded a few changed files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

as you've suggested in your tags, DFS is a good solution to ensure consistency between servers, especially if you've already get a windows cluster configured.

Worth noting, only use DFS if you are using windows 2003 r2; versions of win2k3 prior to this are notoriously unreliable and will result in corruption of your data.

If you're unable to configure DFS for whatever reason, you could use a scheduled task to run robocopy or xcopy to mirror. I would recommend robocopy /MIR as it's easy to implement, and quite reliable.

Comment: +1 for robocopy if the files don't need to be in sync in real time.

Comment: Does that work both ways?

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's new msdeploy framework. I wrote a blog posting about how to use it with IIS6 a while back
http://quickanddirtyscripting.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/msdeploy-with-iis6/

You can get it from www.iis.net

Comment: Thanks but don't think its suitable. Its more for users who upload the odd few pictures which should work from both web servers.